# Using the lerp function (Processing) to change position

Tags: java, processing, lerp

+++ EDIT +++

I have a grid of individual rectangles. Now I want to move each of the individual rectangles with the Lerp Function to a new position (currently MouseX, MouseY). So far I only manage to lerp the grid as a whole – with an unwanted distorsion... this is probably due to the translate(); and the bracket from PushMatrix(); PopMatrix();?

Would I have to build the grid completely differently to make each of the individual rectangles flow to the mouse pointer?
Or is lerp(); just the wrong function to do this?

This is how far I have come so far:

```
float size;
float pixel;
float lx;
float ly;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  pixel = 100;
  size = width/pixel;
  rectMode(CENTER);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  //DRAW THE GRID

  lx = 0;
  ly = 0;

  for (int y = 0; y < pixel; y++) {
    ly = lerp(ly, mouseY, 0.05);
    for (int x = 0; x < pixel; x++) {
      lx = lerp(lx, mouseX, 0.05);
      pushMatrix();
      translate(size/2, size/2);
      translate(x*size, y*size);
      rotate(radians(45));
      fill(255);
      noStroke();
      rect(lx, ly, size, size);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }
}
```

Is this even possible with the way I built the grid?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what you're trying to achieve: you'd like to 'attract'/ease each rotated rectangle towards the mouse (therefore distorting the original grid). Is this correct ?

Comment: Exactly, that is what I am trying to achieve. Im just trying to learn how to rearrange the individual parts from such a grid. With a visible movement to the new place, respectively to the new order. And I thought, to choose the mouse pointer as such a new place would be a first good step. But I don't know if the lerp function is the right tool for this.
But yes, as you describe it, that's what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Your lerp function is used to calculate steps between two positions, so you want the starting position and ending position for your transition, and you will be calling lerp multiple times to recalculate each step.  You can think of lerp as calculating the percentage of the distance between the source and destination as you change the last parameter from 0.0 to 1.0 in incremental steps.

```
rectY=?;
rectX=?; // Replace the '?' marks with the left and top starting positions of your rectangle
for (int step=1; step<=20; step++) {
    lx = lerp(rectX, mouseX, 0.05 * step);
    ly = lerp(rectY, mouseY, 0.05 * step);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I edited my code above - but it still does not work the way I want to… Is maybe lerp(); the wrong function for this?

Comment: I don't know anything about what all your other methods do.  If this is for a class project, I would see if there are advisors that can help you get straightened out.  I think there are some fundamentals like when/how to use floats vs. integers and whether you might need to be performing your loop outside of this class and passing variables into your draw method.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the easing via `lerp()`.

Here's a simplified example using a single grid element:

```java
float easeAmount = 0.05;

float lx, ly;

void setup(){
  size(600, 600); 
}

void draw(){
  lx = lerp(lx, mouseX, easeAmount);
  ly = lerp(ly, mouseY, easeAmount);
  
  background(0);
  quad(lx, ly, 30);
}

void quad(float x, float y, float size){
  float halfSize = size * 0.5;
  quad(x            , y - halfSize, // top
       x + halfSize , y           , // right
       x            , y + halfSize, // bottom
       x - halfSize , y             // left
       );
}
```

manual easing is very similar:

```java
float easeAmount = 0.05;

float lx, ly;

void setup(){
  size(600, 600); 
}

void draw(){
  lx += (mouseX - lx) * easeAmount;
  ly += (mouseY - ly) * easeAmount;;
  
  background(0);
  quad(lx, ly, 30);
}

void quad(float x, float y, float size){
  float halfSize = size * 0.5;
  quad(x            , y - halfSize, // top
       x + halfSize , y           , // right
       x            , y + halfSize, // bottom
       x - halfSize , y             // left
       );
}
```

The idea of the sketches above is to simplyify back to a single element (and discarding push/pop matrix and rotate calls)

One catch with your approach is that you have a single pair of `lx/ly` coordiantes for all the grid elements: it might be easier to have independent pairs: one for each element.

Here's an example using a 2D array to store a pair of eased locations for each grid element:

```java
float easeAmount = 0.05;

// rows and columns
int gridSize = 100;
int numElements = gridSize * gridSize;

float gridElementSize = 6;

float[][] positions = new float[numElements][2];

void setup(){
  size(600, 600); 
  
  // initialise grid positions
  int elementIndex = 0;
  for(int y = 0 ; y < gridSize; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < gridSize; x++){
      // grid x position
      positions[elementIndex][0] = x * gridElementSize; 
      // grid y position
      positions[elementIndex][1] = y * gridElementSize; 
      // increment element counter
      elementIndex++;
    }
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  
  for(int elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < numElements; elementIndex++){
    positions[elementIndex][0]  = lerp(positions[elementIndex][0] , mouseX, easeAmount);
    positions[elementIndex][1]  = lerp(positions[elementIndex][1] , mouseY, easeAmount);
    
    // render updated quad
    quad(positions[elementIndex][0], positions[elementIndex][1], gridElementSize);
  }
  
}

void quad(float x, float y, float size){
  float halfSize = size * 0.5;
  quad(x            , y - halfSize, // top
       x + halfSize , y           , // right
       x            , y + halfSize, // bottom
       x - halfSize , y             // left
       );
}
```

Notice the individual elements move towards the mouse, however the move at the same speed, appearing to move as a group.

You can however add a bit of randomness to break the monotonous movement:

```java
float easeAmount = 0.05;

// rows and columns
int gridSize = 100;
int numElements = gridSize * gridSize;

float gridElementSize = 6;

float[][] positions = new float[gridSize * gridSize][2];

void setup(){
  size(600, 600); 
  noStroke();
  // initialise grid positions
  int elementIndex = 0;
  for(int y = 0 ; y < gridSize; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < gridSize; x++){
      // grid x position
      positions[elementIndex][0] = x * gridElementSize; 
      // grid y position
      positions[elementIndex][1] = y * gridElementSize; 
      // increment element counter
      elementIndex++;
    }
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  // render all quads in one go
  beginShape(QUADS);
  for(int elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < numElements; elementIndex++){
      positions[elementIndex][0]  = lerp(positions[elementIndex][0] , mouseX, random(easeAmount));
      positions[elementIndex][1]  = lerp(positions[elementIndex][1] , mouseY, random(easeAmount));
      
      // render updated quad
      quad(positions[elementIndex][0], positions[elementIndex][1], gridElementSize);
  }
  endShape();
  
}

void quad(float x, float y, float size){
  float halfSize = size * 0.5;
  vertex(x            , y - halfSize); // top
  vertex(x + halfSize , y           ); // right
  vertex(x            , y + halfSize); // bottom
  vertex(x - halfSize , y           ); // left
}
```

Feel free to explore other options.

It might help encapsulating the functionality in a reusable class and making use of `PVector`. If this is an advanced topic at this moment check out [Daniel Shiffman's Nature of Code videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zv9Y_ErUPoM&ab_channel=TheCodingTrain) and (free) online book.

Here's a modified version of Daniel Shiffman's Repeller example modified to use a grid:

```java
// The Nature of Code
// Daniel Shiffman
// http://natureofcode.com

ParticleSystem ps;
Repeller repeller;

void setup() {
  size(600,600);
  strokeWeight(6);
  
  ps = new ParticleSystem(new PVector(width/2,50));
  repeller = new Repeller(width/2-20,height/2);
  
}

void draw() {
  repeller.position.set(mouseX, mouseY);
  
  background(255);
  
  ps.applyRepeller(repeller);
  
  ps.run();
}

void mousePressed(){
  repeller.G = -1000;
}

void mouseReleased(){
  repeller.G = 1000;
}

// The Nature of Code
// Daniel Shiffman
// http://natureofcode.com

class Particle {
  PVector position;
  PVector velocity;
  PVector acceleration;
  float lifespan;
  
  float mass = 100; // Let's do something better here!
  
  PVector initialPosition;
  
  Particle(PVector l) {
    initialPosition = l.get();
    reset();
  }
  
  void reset(){
    acceleration = new PVector(0,0);
    velocity = new PVector();
    position = initialPosition.get();
    lifespan = 255.0;
  }

  void run() {
    update();
    display(g);
  }

  void applyForce(PVector force) {
    PVector f = force.get();
    f.div(mass);   
    acceleration.add(f);
  }

  // Method to update position
  void update() {
    velocity.add(acceleration);
    position.add(velocity);
    acceleration.mult(0);
    lifespan -= .2;
  }

  // Method to display
  void display(PGraphics g) {
    g.stroke(0,lifespan);
    g.vertex(position.x,position.y);
  }

  // Is the particle still useful?
  boolean isDead() {
    if (lifespan < 0.0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

// The Nature of Code
// Daniel Shiffman
// http://natureofcode.com

class ParticleSystem {
  ArrayList<Particle> particles;
  PVector origin;
  
  int numParticles = 10000;
  int particleIndex = 0;

  ParticleSystem(PVector position) {
    origin = position.get();
    particles = new ArrayList<Particle>();
    for(int i = 0; i < numParticles; i++){
      addParticle();
    }
  }

  void addParticle() {
    particles.add(new Particle(new PVector(particleIndex % 100 * 6, particleIndex / 100 * 6)));
    particleIndex++;
  }

  // A function to apply a force to all Particles
  void applyForce(PVector f) {
    for (Particle p: particles) {
      p.applyForce(f);
    }
  }

  void applyRepeller(Repeller r) {
    for (Particle p: particles) {
      PVector force = r.repel(p);        
      p.applyForce(force);
    }
  }


  void run() {
    beginShape(POINTS);
    for (int i = particles.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
      Particle p = particles.get(i);
      p.run();
      if (p.isDead()) {
        //particles.remove(i);
        p.reset();
      }
    }
    endShape();
  }
}

// The Nature of Code
// Daniel Shiffman
// http://natureofcode.com

// Particles + Forces

// A very basic Repeller class
class Repeller {
  
  // Gravitational Constant
  float G = 1000;
  // position
  PVector position;
  float r = 10;

  Repeller(float x, float y)  {
    position = new PVector(x,y);
  }

  void display() {
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(2);
    fill(175);
    ellipse(position.x,position.y,48,48);
  }

  // Calculate a force to push particle away from repeller
  PVector repel(Particle p) {
    PVector dir = PVector.sub(position,p.position);      // Calculate direction of force
    float d = dir.mag();                       // Distance between objects
    dir.normalize();                           // Normalize vector (distance doesn't matter here, we just want this vector for direction)
    d = constrain(d,5,100);                    // Keep distance within a reasonable range
    float force = -1 * G / (d * d);            // Repelling force is inversely proportional to distance
    dir.mult(force);                           // Get force vector --> magnitude * direction
    return dir;
  }  
}
```

Notice the particles fade (based on `Particle`'s lifespan) and then reset

(This reminds of an effect a friend of mine coded a decade ago in JS: http://js1k.com/2011-trail/demo/908 . It used plain JS, but still conceptually uses the equivalent of a class to represent each particle which has properties that control velocity and position).

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much! This helps me a looot! Thank you for taking the time to explain it… I will study it and keep you posted on my progress!